# How to change socket pdo_mysql uses?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sockets

I have a jQuery plugin (dataTables) that I'm trying to turn into a WordPress plugin, but the issue I'm running into is that WordPress uses a different socket for mysql (mysqld.sock) than what the plugin is expecting (mysql.sock). The plugin throws this error when being used:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through
>   socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Would changing the socket **pdo_mysql** uses to mysqld.sock fix this issue? If so, how would I go about changing the socket **pdo_mysql** uses?

I created a phpinfo.php file and this is what it returned:

**mysql:**

`mysql._defaultsocket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` (this file and directory exist)

**pdo_mysql:**

`pdo_mysql.default_socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` (this file and directory do not exist)

Comment: Why not use Wordpress' built in `$wpdb` class for database access?

Comment: Could you explain how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Common problem after an upgrade, conflicting defaults, You could: (1) try to connect with `127.0.0.1`  instead of `localhost`, as it usually prevents connecting by socket (2) connect by explicit socket (use `unix_socket` in the [`DSN`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) (3) hunt down all files which supply the socket path, and make sure they are in sync (have the same socket configuration). You can find out which files are read by invoking `mysql --help` from the cli (for me they're: `/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf `).